# Disable Bright Colors in TTY

Tags: linux, colors, tty

I've been searching for a way to disable the bright (bold) colours in a TTY (colours 8 to 15). I'd like all bright colours to use their half-bright counterparts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the [terminfo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo) database for your terminal type under `/usr/share/terminfo` — it should be a file named the same as the value of your `TERM` variable.  Remember its pathname.

Decompile the database file into source using `infocmp $TERM > FILE.ti`.  This can be done in your home directory, because infocmp will find the right database file based on the value of `$TERM`.

Edit `FILE.ti` and remove the entry `bold=...` from the comma-separate list of name=value pairs.  Save the file, and recompile it using `tic FILE.ti`.  This will replace `FILE` in the same directory.

Make a new directory under your home directory named `.terminfo`.  Also make any subdirectories under `~/.terminfo` necessary to match the subdirectories under `/usr/share/terminfo` where you found `FILE`.  Now copy both `FILE` and `FILE.ti` into the  subdirectory under `~/.terminfo` that matches the subdirectory under `/usr/share/terminfo` where you found `FILE`.  For example, if you have files named `xterm` and `xterm.ti`, you would copy them to directory `~/.terminfo/x` because you found `xterm` in `/usr/share/terminfo/x`.

Next add this line to your `~/.bashrc` startup script: `export TERMINFO="$HOME/.terminfo"`, and close and re-open your terminal window.

This should disable the `bold` operation for that terminal type, and all colors should only appear in their dim form.

Comment: Actually, the `tic FILE.ti` command may have to be `tic -o. FILE.ti`, which forces it to write the compiled terminfo file into the current directory.  Sorry about that omission.

Comment: When all is said and done, you can verify where terminfo is getting your terminal's database from by running `infocmp $TERM`.  Near the top of the output should be a line of the form: `# Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /cygdrive/c/franl/.terminfo/r/rxvt`.  That filename is where terminfo is getting your terminal's database from.

Comment: Thanks for this! Really appreciate it. Interestingly when I used `tic FILE.ti` it wrote it to the correct place (`$HOME/.terminfo/l/linux`). I didn't need to copy both `FILE` and `FILE.ti` to the subdir, just `FILE`. Also the changes were picked up without editing my `.bashrc`.

Comment: Glad it worked.  The behavior you describe may be because you already have a `TERMINFO` environment variable set to `$HOME/.terminfo`.  It might be something the default shell startup scripts on your Linux distribution set up for you.

Comment: I'm running Arch, checked `TERMINFO` but it contains nothing. Not a problem anyway, just something I found interesting.